# Chain Rule - Partial Derivatives - dw/dt

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Express dw/dt as function of **t**, if **w = xy**, **x = cos t**, **y = sen t**, **z = t**

My first step is to sketch the tree.

*w - x - t*

*w - y - t*

*w - z - t*

---

dw/dx =  y

dw/dy = x

dw/dz = 1

Then:

dx/dt = -sen t

dy/dt = cos t

dz/dt = 1

Then:

-ysent + xcost + 1

Changing the x and y to "cos t and sen t"

Result:

- **-sen²t + cos²t + 1**

But the teacher's answer is: **1 + cos2t**

What's is incorrect?

Comment: $\cos(2t)=\cos^2t-\sin^2t$

Comment: Your answer is the same as your teacher's answer. But both looks incorrect to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. They used the identity

$$ \cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x $$

to obtain what was written.

Comment: Oh, really? Thanks a lot, guy! I suspected that! I visited many websites to check some identity. Thanks, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$$
$$=y(-\sin t)+x \cos t + 0\times 1$$
$$=\cos^2 t-\sin^2 t=\cos 2t$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!